# Why was this question on an offensive term closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm not sure why [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87129/is-far-east-politically-incorrect) was closed, as it seems like a perfectly valid inquiry on whether or not a certain expression is considered sensitive or offensive in the English language. This seems like quite a valid question, and others like it have been asked. It seems like useful information to know whether or not a term is offensive, and it directly pertains to English, as it is an English expression. Why exactly was this question closed?

Answer (score 9):

It's not a real question.  The title gives the impression of a question, but the text simply says "Look what I found.  Interesting, eh?".  If you had worded the main text to make it clear you were serious about the question and to show some constructive argument, it might still be open.

Comment: I agree. Had the user asked if the term could be construed as offensive, it would have had more merit. But instead the so-called question came off more as pontificating than inquiring.

Comment: @itsbruce The core question was still on whether or not the term was politically correct. As repugnant as I found the argumentative subtext (as can be seen in my answer), I don't think that it took away from the true question.

Comment: I don't like questions where the question is only in the title and the text only provides commentary.  Smells like trolling even where it isn't.

Comment: Also, worth noting is that I am not the author of the question "If *you* had worded the main text...".